# Haskell - How can I use Maybe in IO function

Tags: haskell

```hs
main ::  IO ()
main = do
    result <- function_returns_io_maybe -- type of result is Maybe x
    -- if result maybe is Just, run function that return IO() with result, else do not run function.
```

How can I use Maybe in IO function?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of your example. Is it `function_returns_io_maybe :: Maybe (IO a)`? And then you want the `IO a` to execute if it exists? So for example, `function_returns_io_maybe = Just (putStrLn "Hello")` and then you want to print "Hello"?

Comment: This question could easily be clearer. Is the type of the function IO (Maybe x) or Maybe (IO x).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write any expression within a `do` block, as long as the expression has the correct monadic type for that block. In particular, you can do case analysis:

```
main = do
  result <- something
  case result of
    Just r -> somethingElse r
    Nothing -> return ()
```

(where `something :: IO (Maybe X); somethingElse :: X -> IO ()`)

Personally, I’d write that with a lambda case and a bind:

```
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}

main = something >>= \case
  Just r -> somethingElse r
  Nothing -> return ()
```

Case analysis on a `Maybe` is more succinctly written with the [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) combinator:

```
main = maybe somethingElse (return ()) =<< something
```

And [`Control.Monad.Extra.whenJustM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.10/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:whenJustM) captures this entire sort of operation:

```
import Control.Monad.Extra (whenJustM)

main = whenJustM something somethingElse
```

Comment: That `whenJustM` seems silly. We already have `mapM_` (or `traverse_` if you prefer) for that: `main = something >>= mapM_ somethingElse`.